# I want to upgrade my 2020 Allez from Claris to Shimano 105

Tags: road-bike, shimano, shifter, upgrades, groupsets

I have a 2020 Specalized Allez that came with Shimano Claris, but since I live in a very hilly area, I feel as if I need more gears. I have been biking for a while now, but I don't know if I need to train more or need more gears. The inclines that I find myself needing more gears on are over 10%. I am wondering if I can just put in a 105 rear and front derailleur, and keep my original brakes. I am also wondering if I have to get new rims to compensate for the extra 3 gears I am putting in, or if I can just put a more narrow spacer in the back.

Thanks for reading!

Edit: For those of you wondering, I have the base claris gearing system, so an 11-32 cassete in the back and 34-56 in the front. Thank you all for your help. When going up 5-12% inclines, I don't need to shift all the way down, its usually in-between 13-25% inclines that I find myself using my smallest gear. I will probably train more for the next month or two and then see if I still need to upgrade! Thanks everyone.

Comment: To climb hills you need lower gears, not more gears.  More gears are very nice in that the spacing gets smaller and you have the right one, but the lowest  gear is set by the ratio of your small chain ring to your large cog on the back.  What do you have now?  The website shows the small chainring as 34, but doesn't say what the large cog in the rear is.

Comment: Yea Specialized did not say what cassette the bike comes with.

Comment: It appears that at least in the US, the stock configuration was 50/34 chainrings with an 11-32, 8s Sunrace cassette. https://www.specialized.com/us/en/allez/p/65227?color=172702-65227&searchText=90015-7149

Comment: So 11-34 could be an option and probably the only one I would do based on the cost of the bike. I would ride the wheels off of it and then look to purchase an entry level carbon bike that has 105 vs. trying to upgrade it to 105. Again to each is their own and if you really would like to go all out and upgrade thing it is after all your money and bike.

Comment: Your Claris cassette is 8 speed, would you be happy with 10 speed 105 rather than the newer 11 speed variant?  Staying with 10 means you won't need a new rear wheel/freehub.

Comment: Would you be happy to run a Claris left lever for the front and a 105 right lever for the rear?  The differences may be enough to annoy some riders - that would let you only replace the right-hand shifter, rear derailleur, cassette and chain.

Answer (score 4):

To go to 105 you would have to do the following:

- Front + Rear Derailleur
- Cassette, Chain Rings
- Chain
- STI Lever (at least the right one) - This alone is like $150 per lever if I recall correctly.
- Possibly new rear wheel

Overall most people will not make a jump from Claris to 105 because the costs usually end up being almost the same price as 50% or more of the value of the bike.

Now 105 to Ultegra/Dura-Ace is more common and cost effective (e.g. As I wear out components in the drivetrain I am replacing them to Ultegra).

What you can do or at least what I would do is this:

Check your current number of teeth on your largest gear on your cassette and count the teeth on your chain ring. If you are struggling on climbs I would try the follow in this order:

- If your cassette is not 11-34 Claris I would spend the $20 or so and try that: [Link](https://cambriabike.com/products/shimano-hg50-8-speed-mtb-cassette?variant=28025636847690&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cse&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&adpos=&scid=scplpGM041719128&sc_intid=GM041719128&gclid=Cj0KCQiAoab_BRCxARIsANMx4S7iQJI33dwkN62Y4vj8KvsrfFGYxGLWwvkWARMT_mPrlUGHO9uXU1caAuBxEALw_wcB)
- If you are still struggling on climbs replace your chain ringings to 46-34T. This will not necessarily make the climb easier because you still have a 34 T chain ring and max 34 T cog in the back, but it will make flatter portions feel easier, which can make the climb feel more doable: [Claris Chain Ring](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/claris-r2000/FC-RS200.html)
- Save the money you would have otherwise spent on a 105 upgrade and use it towards a full carbon bike with 105 or Ultegra (e.g. Trek Domane SL5 and I think Specialized Roubaix not sure of which trim though).

Here is the important thing to realize though it will not get easier even with 105 or another bike (assuming both bikes are of equal weight/aero/etc.) if your cassette already is 11-34. The reason being is that 34T is the max size rear gear you can get whether it is 105 or claris and the smallest inner chain ring on both sets is 34T.

Also, are you sure the gradient is 20%. That is pretty steep for a bike - [Link](https://www.wired.com/2013/03/whats-the-steepest-gradient-for-a-road-bike/). Many cyclist will have to walk that:

Here is what 7% or so looks like as a reference near the end:

In that clip, I am in a 34 T chain ring and the 4th cog of a 105 11-34 cassette. So to your other point with training climbing 7-10% is possible even for an amateur.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @TudeProductions thanks for the help! The majority of incline in my rides is under 10% (I miss typed, and said 20), but some of the steepest parts in my rides even go up to 25%.

Comment: I think OP is asking about upgrading from an 8 speed casette to an 11 speed casette ¿is that even possible without spreading the frame? Given this is an aluminium frame i would think that cannot be done.

Comment: @ÁngelCáceresLicona It is definitely possible. 8s and 11s don’t require any different frame spacing. 11 speed road requires a wider freehub body, but most road bikes nowadays come with that wide FH body and use a 1.85mm spacer to make up for the difference when using a 8/9/10s cassette.

Comment: IIRC you can get an 11-34 in the HG50 range (Claris) and keep 8 speeds all be it the jumps may be bigger and the easiest upgrade if the OP is looking for 34T for the hills

Comment: The 46-34 crankset will not help at all. The small chainring is still the same as on a 50-34 compact. It is for people wanting smaller top gear, not smaller granny gear.

Comment: @JamesJordan For your next bike consider gravel gearing or other **sub**compact crankset.  An 46-34 won't  help. You need the 34 to go to 32 or even 30. So you want 46-30.

Comment: @VladimirF good point. Unfortunately, right now it doesn’t seem like the big 3 manufacturers are seriously considering sub-compact for road bikes. Right now, most road cyclists will need to go aftermarket to get a sub-compact crankset on a road (not gravel) bike. Or get a gravel bike, which can certainly be used on road.

Comment: @JamesJordan - Train harder ; ) and stick to a road bike (many of them now also later allow for wider tires to be fit so they can be converted to a gravel bike later). I would love to be around 25% gradients to be able to train on them. Just as an FYI that 7.5% gradient used to be hard for me and I was spinning in 34-34. A few months later it is not that big of a deal. Note I mix in running and weights to my training as well.

Comment: I disagree that road bikes can be converted to gravel bikes. This may just be semantics, but while many current generation endurance bikes can take 32-35mm tires, current generation gravel bikes can take over 40mm tires. 32mm can suffice in many places, but I think most observers wouldn’t consider it a true gravel width tire.

Comment: @WeiwenNg - Valid points that there is a point where a dedicated gravel bike will be the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

You could get a 33 teeth small chainring and a 11–34 teeth cassette. Compared to your currently installed 34t chainring and 11–32t cassette it would make things 8% easier.

One thing which took me a long time to realize: It’s possible to pedal quite slow. Usually you should pedal at about 90rpm, but when going up steep hills it can be necessary to drop down to ~70rpm. Do so early enough, otherwise you’ll run out of steam in the middle of the hill. Just try to take it slow and easy. When you go out of the saddle you can pedal even slower, like 60rpm. Quite often it’s even necessary to shift one gear up before you go out of the saddle, to have the right amount of resistance.

That being said, I do think that it’s a good idea to have easy enough gears, especially for (easy) training rides or long rides (possibly with luggage). There is also no shame in dismounting and pushing the bike uphill, it’s not much slower than riding at ~9km/h (though can be hard in cycling shoes).

Comment: Does Shimano even make that standard for their road bikes? https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/claris-r2000/FC-RS200.html

Comment: @TudeProductions: Not Shimano themselves but for example I’m using this [TA Specialites Zephyr Chainrings Road 110mm Compact Shimano](https://www.bike24.com/p25832.html) chainring with 33t on my cyclocross/touring bike. Doesn't require any special screws (I think there are also 32t rings with special screws) and should be compatible to the Claris crankset.

Comment: Found the 32t solution, but it’s expensive (and oval, if you don’t like that): https://absoluteblack.cc/oval-sub-compact-chainrings-48-32-for-110-5-bcd/ (200€ for the set). 4 arm chainrings with 110mm BCD and 32t are less expensive, e.g. from FSA: https://shop.fullspeedahead.com/en/type/chainrings/chainrings/road/vero-pro-chainring

Comment: @Michael Wouldn't oval chainrings make climbing harder?  Isn't their effective diameter [***larger*** on the pedal downstroke since that's the most powerful part of the pedal stroke?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/14990/whats-the-correct-position-to-assemble-eliptic-biopace-rotor-etc-chainrings)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Well, the idea is that your legs are more powerful in that position, so one could argue that climbing should be easier with them. I do have oval chainrings on the training road bike. Can’t really tell a difference but *maybe* under high load, low rpm I can pedal a tad smoother.